# Microsoft SQL Server: Any way to tell when a record was created?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Our customer wants to order by the record creation date.  To me this seems like a system variable, some sort of meta data for the record itself.

Is there a way to tell when a record was created without actually creating a datetime field with a default of GetDate() and hope that no one modifies it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Nope.

You need to have a column for this.

Imagine how big the meta-data would be if you needed to keep a record for each record for creation!  Would you also want to keep meta-data on your meta-data so you know when the meta-data was updated?  The space use can quickly escalate.

SQL Server keeps some stats but something this specific will need to come from a user-defined field.

As a side note, you can make it more difficult to tamper with the date on your created field if you use a lookup table.  Create a table "TableName_CreateDate" and use the PK from your actual table and a date value.  Your date is in a separate location and less likely to be modified but you can still `JOIN` on it to get your order.  You would need to create a trigger to update this with new values.

If you only want the **DATE** and don't need a datetime value, you can go one step further and just have a table of dates and a lookup table that joins to that.  I.e.:

`Table->Table.PK + Date.Pk -> DateTable`

This would save a lot of drive space if you have a lot of rows (4 bytes per row I think).

Comment: Security by obfuscation is never a good idea. If you need the create date to not be modified for audit purposes or something guaranteed you should use a database user that does not have permission to update the createdate field, only create it.

Answer (score 5):

The creationdate field should be added. You fix the ' hope that no one modifies it" part by adding a trigger on update that does not allow that field to be updated, ever.

Answer (score 1):

No, not even in the system tables to my knowledge. You could dig through old transaction logs I'm sure, but natively, no.

Answer (score 0):

I once came with a kind of situation where order of the rows of a table is required but no timestamp (CreateDateTime, UpdateDateTime, ..., etc.) column is available. So, only data I had was the transaction log. Reading transaction log directly was not helpful as it is not easy to parse. Hence, I found a program called "ApexSQL Log" which was very helpful. It has all filtering options and you can read all log data without hardcore operations. Although this solution was satisfactory for me, it has a drawback: You can only filter date (Begin Time and End Time) according to transaction operation. If you are searching for a query operation, for example an insert, which is encapsulated in a transaction, you can not retrieve the exact insert time (at least I could not find a way), only the transaction time. If your operations are all atomic, then you can literaly have all row create date information.

Answer (score -4):

If he only wants to order by it, you can consider using a [timestamp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776%28SQL.90%29.aspx) column.

It cannot be related to a real-world date, but you can sort on it.

Comment: He may have issues if they want to compare between tables down the road with this method, though.

Comment: no biggie as long as the OP knows all the benefits and risks. :)

Comment: Aah! I just thought I made a mistake in this answer, but now I think I didn't. It's time for bed. Anyway, mod it down if it's no use ;)

Comment: `timestamp` fields are automatically updated on every update to a row.  This breaks his "and make sure it doesn't change" functionality pretty thoroughly.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it would not be a creation stamp but a modification stamp.